# Заменить строки в txt

Tags: c#, строки, замена

Формат txt файла:

```
19,"n","d","m"
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08435059
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
1.00000000,262.08432007
```

19 - количество строк.
Нужно заменить (в данном случае) цифру 1 на числа от 0 до 180 с шагом 10, т.е. Должно получиться:

```
19,"n","d","m"
0.00000000,262.08432007
10.00000000,262.08432007
20.00000000,262.08432007
30.00000000,262.08432007
40.00000000,262.08432007
50.00000000,262.08432007
60.00000000,262.08432007
70.00000000,262.08432007
80.00000000,262.08435059
90.00000000,262.08432007
100.00000000,262.08432007
110.00000000,262.08432007
120.00000000,262.08432007
130.00000000,262.08432007
140.00000000,262.08432007
150.00000000,262.08432007
160.00000000,262.08432007
170.00000000,262.08432007
180.00000000,262.08432007
```

В данном примере от 0 до 180 с шагом 10, т.е. 19 строк.
Но может быть и другой шаг (1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6,9, 10, 12, 15, 18,20,30, 36, 45)

Comment: При другом шаге количество строк, соответственно, будет другое. Оно прописывается всегда

Comment: А в чем у вас трудности? Вы не знаете как посчитать файл? Или как его записать обратно? Или как сделать замену в строке?

Comment: Я не силён в этом. Время от времени нужно решить такие задачки. Я стараюсь, но..Понимаю, что это не сайт фрилансеров, и в то же время понимаю, что задача очень простая...

Comment: *Я не силён в этом* - в каком конкретно вопросе? Я их три назвал. Если в каждом, то надо задать их отдельно, вопрос пока слишком общий

Comment: В интернете много информации по считыванию файла, с этим более-менее. Затем, как ответил @Nova 'var splits = string.Split(',');' . Далее 'ar result = double.Parse(splits[0]);' Далее самые сложности - замена.

Comment: Если файл не слишком большой, то читаете его в память целиком как массив строк, изменяете их как вам надо и записываете все обратно. Если большой то переписываете построчно в новый файл изменяя прочитанные строки, можете потом удалить старый и переименовать новый если нужно. Без пересоздания можно только заменить отдельные символы один к одному, если нужно что-то вставить, а вам нужно именно это, т.к. длина строк увеличивается, то придется писать по новой, "раздвинуть" байты в файле нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Читаешь построчно файл, строки заносишь в список строк (List  ).
Как прочитал весь файл, в цикле по списку разделяешь строки (var splits = string.Split(',');) и первый элемент парсишь (var result = double.Parse(splits[0]);) добавляешь к нему требуемое слагаемое. Далее из полученной суммы и остатка от разделения строки формируешь новую строку, и добавляешь её в новый список измененных строк. Вуаля!